# Managing more than one slider in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I'm new to html and recognize this may be a basic question.  However I haven't been able to find any examples of this sort of functionality yet.  I'm trying to do math with the input from two different sliders. Thus far, my code looks like this:

```js
function f(x, y) {
  return x + y
}

function sliderx(value) {
  val = f(value, 1.0)
  console.log(val)
}
```

```html
<h1> Slider Test</h1>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<p> sliderx </p>
<form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
  <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" step="0.05" min="0.0" max="1.0" value="get_min() " oninput="sliderx(this.value)">
  <output name="amount" for="rangeInput"></output>
</form>
<p> slidery </p>
<form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
  <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" step="0.05" min="0.0" max="1.0" value="get_min() " oninput="slidery(this.value)">
  <output name="amount" for="rangeInput"></output>
</form>
```

I created two sliders (**sliderx** and **slidery**) and defined f(x,y) = x+y.  My goal is to be able to print x+y to console.log. I can call **silderx** and my console updates accordingly for fixed y. However, I don't see any good way to update y using **slidery**, while keeping x defined by **sliderx**.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: First note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: You are mixing together a number of different methods for handling updating the DOM and the result is a bit of a tangle. Since you are using an `<output>` element and an inline calculation I would say just stick with that. The documentation has an example of your exact question (though it uses one slider and one number input). See: [<output>: The Output element: Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output#examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, there is a solution for your problem!

To achieve your goal, you can define two global variables x and y to store the current values of the sliders, and update them whenever the slider values change. Then, you can calculate `f(x,y)` using the updated values of x and y, and log the result to the console. Also as your comments also mentioned IDs should be unique so stick with unique IDs and names for your elements. See:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=q, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <title>What's the date?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Slider Test</h1>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <p>sliderx</p>
    <form oninput="amount.value=rangeInputX.value">
      <input
        type="range"
        id="sliderx"
        name="rangeInputX"
        step="0.05"
        min="0.0"
        max="1.0"
        value="get_min()"
        oninput="update()"
      />
      <output name="amount" for="sliderx"></output>
    </form>
    <p>slidery</p>
    <form oninput="amount.value=rangeInputY.value">
      <input
        type="range"
        id="slidery"
        name="rangeInputY"
        step="0.05"
        min="0.0"
        max="1.0"
        value="get_min()"
        oninput="update()"
      />
      <output name="amount" for="slidery"></output>
    </form>
    <script>
      //Initialize your sliders with current start values
      let sliderx = document.getElementById("sliderx");
      let slidery = document.getElementById("slidery");
      let x = sliderx.value;
      let y = slidery.value;
      console.log(x, y);

      function update() {
        x = parseFloat(sliderx.value);
        y = parseFloat(slidery.value);
        const result = f(x, y);
        console.log(
          ` ${x} (Value of sliderx:) + ${y} (Value of slidery) = ${result}`
        );
      }

      function f(x, y) {
        return x + y;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this implementation, we define two global variables x and y to store the current values of the sliders. Whenever a slider value changes, the update function is called, which `updates the values of x and y`, calculates `f(x,y)`, and logs the result to the console. The update function is called whenever either slider value changes, using the `oninput` attribute of the slider inputs. The `output` elements are associated with their corresponding slider inputs using the `for` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I certainly wouldn't have guessed this - but his makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score -1):

```js
function f(x, y) {
  return x + y
}

function sliderx(value) {
  let val = f(value, 1.0)
  console.log(val)
}
function slidery(value) {
  let val = f(value, 1.0)
  console.log(val)
}
```

```html
<h1> Slider Test</h1>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<p> sliderx </p>
<form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
  <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" step="0.05" min="0.0" max="1.0" value="get_min() " oninput="sliderx(this.value)">
  <output name="amount" for="rangeInput"></output>
</form>
<p> slidery </p>
<form oninput="amountY.value=rangeInputY.value">
  <input type="range" id="rangeInputY" name="rangeInputY" step="0.05" min="0.0" max="1.0" value="get_min() " oninput="slidery(this.value)">
  <output name="amountY" for="rangeInputY"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: that does not save the x value in f(x, y). x is always being updated this way